# Java Regex Pattern Matcher.matches() before Matcher.find() Strange behaviour

Tags: java, regex

I tried this example just interchanging two lines it gives different outputs why

```
String inputString = "username@gmail.com"; 
String pattern="([a-z]+@)([a-z]+)(\\.[a-z]+)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern); 
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
```

///changes happens here

```
if(m.find()) 
{
   String resultString = m.replaceAll("$1xxxx$3"); 
   System.out.println(resultString); 
}

System.out.println(m.matches());//line to be changed
```

output :

username@xxxx.com

true

```
System.out.println(m.matches());//line changed     
if(m.find()) 
{
   String resultString = m.replaceAll("$1xxxx$3"); 
   System.out.println(resultString); 
}
```

output :
true

Comment: just edited please check.thanks for concern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extracted from [`Matcher.find`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) documentation

> find
>
> public boolean find()
>
> Attempts to find the next subsequence of the
>   input sequence that matches the pattern. This method starts at the
>   beginning of this matcher's region, **or, if a previous invocation of
>   the method was successful and the matcher has not since been reset, at
>   the first character not matched by the previous match**.
>
> If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained via the
>   start, end, and group methods.
>
> Returns: true if, and only if, a subsequence of the input sequence
>   matches this matcher's pattern

So, since you called `Matcher.matches` which attempts to match the whole String, and you did not reset the matcher, it tried to find starting after the first match. As there is only one match, it does not find anything.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()

Find starts wherever it was left off from the previous use of the matcher

First instance, this means the start of the inputString.

However, as matches() takes the whole inputString into account, this moves the pointer to the end. As a result, it finds no more and find() in this case is false (as its subsequent)

Answer (score 2):

The javadoc for the method replaceAll(String replacement) states the following
"Invoking this method changes this matcher's state. If the matcher is to be used in further matching operations then it should first be reset."

So, I think you are finding this discrepancy because the matcher is not longer in the same state after replaceall. Try resetting the matcher after replaceall.